# How to extract frames from this GIF image? (Access violation in TGIFRenderer.Draw)

Tags: delphi, graphics, gif, delphi-xe7

I have this functions that extracts frames from animated GIFs. It works with all GIFs except this one: [image]

```
{ Loads a GIF. Returns a list of BMP frames }
function GetGifFrames(GifFile: string): TObjectList;
var
  GIF: TGIFImage;
  TempFrame: TBitmap; 
  Frame: TBitmap;
  Counter: Integer;
  GR: TGIFRenderer;
begin
 { Load GIF }
 GIF := TGIFImage.Create;
 TRY
  TRY
   Gif.Animate := FALSE;
   GIF.LoadFromFile(GifFile);
  EXCEPT
    MesajError('Cannot load '+ GifFile);
    EXIT(NIL);
  END;

  if Gif.Images.Count= 1 then
   begin
     MsgError('This is not an animated GIF'+ CRLF+ GifFile);
     EXIT(NIL);
   end;

  Result:= TObjectList.Create;
  Result.OwnsObjects:= TRUE;                                   { Array of images }

  { GIF render }
  TempFrame:= TBitmap.Create;
  GR:= TGIFRenderer.Create(GIF);                               { GIF render }
  TRY
   TempFrame.SetSize(GIF.Width, GIF.Height);

   for Counter:= 0 to GIF.Images.Count-1 DO
    begin
      { Skip bad frames }
      if GIF.Images[Counter].Empty
      then Continue;

      { Create new frame }
      Frame:= TBitmap.Create;
      Frame.SetSize(GIF.Width, GIF.Height);
      GR.Draw(TempFrame.Canvas, TempFrame.Canvas.ClipRect);   <---------- AV here   { Transfer image from GIF to BMP }     
      Frame.Assign(TempFrame);
      Result.Add(Frame);                                       { Add to list of bitmap frames }
      GR.NextFrame;                                            { Advance }
    end;

  FINALLY
   FreeAndNil(GR);
   FreeAndNil(TempFrame);
  END;

  FINALLY
   FreeAndNil(GIF);
 END;
end;
```

I have an AV on the line indicated above

> Debugger Exception Notification Project Tester.exe raised exception
>   class $C0000005 with message 'access violation at 0x005d3924: read of
>   address 0x0000002c'.

Update: 
   Compilable tester [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=87092305545494126013&t=8709230554549412601366009) or [here](http://www.filedropper.com/giftester).

The stack trace is:

```
   GetGifFrames('C:\Test gif\err.gif')
   GIFImg.TGIFRenderer.Draw($7EFA9070,(0, 0, 108, 146, (0, 0), (108, 146)))
   GIFImg.TGIFRenderer.GetBitmap
   GIFImg.TGIFRenderer.RenderFrame
```

Here in Render frame it crashes on this line:

```
PreviousBuffer.Canvas.CopyRect(PreviousBuffer.Canvas.ClipRect, Buffer.Canvas, Buffer.Canvas.ClipRect);
```

This is because **PreviousBuffer is NIL**!!!!

How to fix this?

Comment: When you put breakpoint at line `GR.Draw(TempFrame.Canvas, TempFrame.Canvas.ClipRect);` what value stored in `GR` in `TempFrame`?

Comment: @ZamronyP.Juhara - Values for TempFrame.Width and Height are ok (the size of the gif 108x146). ClipRect is also Ok. Maybe this particular GIF is malformed?

Comment: Why is it so difficult to show the complete error message, don't you think there could be some valuable information? BTW, I tested your code as is with the image ("Sansanimated.gif") but no AV, nor any other error, 13 frames in `TObjectList`.

Comment: *Read of address 0x0000002C* looks like access to a nil object reference, and since you only access `TempFrame` and its `Canvas`, is either nil? Of course in your code they shouldn't, but ...

Comment: @TomBrunberg- Hi Tom.   1. Tester (DPR, PAS, DFM file) available here: http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=87092305545494126013&t=8709230554549412601366009   There is also the compiled file (exe) that will show the AV (in case you still cannot repro in your computer).   2. I think you get 'read of address 00000000' when you try to access a nil obj.

Comment: @TomBrunberg-Sorry. My bad. That image worked indeed. I replaced it with the 'broken' image. And yes, the 'broken' gif works in all other programs (including IrfanView).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the properties of a frame in a GIF file is the `DisposalMethod` which defines how the image in the frame should be disposed of in preparation of the next frame. In the original file ("Sansanimated.gif" link at the top of the post) this is set to `dmNoDisposal` for all 13 frames. This works as such in your code without problems. In the file "err.gif" the two frames both have `dmPrevious` which require an extra internal bitmap. This bitmap is not allocated if the `GIFRenderer` is not initialized as being animating.

To have the GIFRenderer properly initialized for frames with `dmPrevious` disposal method setting add one line

```
GR.Animate := True;  // <---- add this line
```

right after creating `GR`.

Comment: Out of curiosity: What makes the code to work for all other GIFs but not for this one?

Comment: Maybe omitting `Gif.Animate := FALSE;` will have the same effect.

Comment: @kobik- Sorry. I don't understand

Comment: @SolarWind, You explicitly added `Gif.Animate := FALSE;` in your code (I don't know why you did) Have you tried removing this line?

Comment: @SolarWind Thanks! The gifs that work do not have the disposal mode set to `dmPrevious`. `dmPrevious` is mostly used for gifs that update only smaller parts of the total image in each frame. I did not have such gif among the ones on my PC.

Comment: @kobik I was thinking the same as you, and tried it, but it had no effect. It could possible help to set `GIF.Animate`after the renderer is created but that would be just the same.

Comment: @kobik - The 'Animate' method starts the animation. Or this is what I thought.    ___      I didn't wanted the GIF image to be animated in background (and to waste CPU).      I wanted to keep the image still and just to extract its frames. So, I set it to false. Probably the method should be named 'IsAnimated' instead of 'Animate'?   :)

Comment: @kobik - PS related to settings Animate to false. If you don't add the [Animate= false] line, the behavior is the same because:   GIFImageDefaultAnimate: boolean = False.   So, with or without Gif.Animate:= false, my code is the same :) :) :)

Comment: @SolarWind, I was only assuming it was an issue b/c I though `GR.Animate` will get this property from the `TGIFImage` itself... in any case glad Tom came with a solution for you and +1.